# Why is it when I print my matrices they do not look like how a matrix should look like?

Tags: python, matrix, addition

Not sure what part of the code is not making the printed matrix look like how a matrix should look like.

```py
print("1st Matrix: ")
for i in range(a):
    for j in range (b):
        print (matrix1[i][j], end=" ")
        print()

print("2nd Matrtix: ")
for i in range (a):
    for j in range(b):
        print (matrix2[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
        
result=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range (a):
    for j in range(b):
        result[i][j]=matrix1[i][j]+matrix2[i][j]
        
print("Result Matrix: ")
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        print(result[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What *does the output look like*, and how *should* it look like? Please be specific, dont make us guess

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to put the `print()` outside of the inner for-loop, but inside the outer for-loop.

Comment: What Paul said. The reason is because you want to print a new line `\n` _after you've finished printing an entire row_

Comment: Thanks, Paul, I am learning Python for the first time. You were correct. I didn't know the position of the print within which looped matters like it does. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check `indentation` in the second `print()` it must arrange with **'i'** loop.

```
#Some sample initial value... 
import random
a=b=3
matrix1=matrix2 = [[random.randint(0, 4)] * b for _ in range(a)]

#Code
print("1st Matrix: ")
for i in range(a):
    for j in range (b):
        print (matrix1[i][j], end=" ")
    print() #  <--- Correct the indentation here 

print("2nd Matrtix: ")
for i in range (a):
    for j in range(b):
        print (matrix2[i][j], end=" ")
    print() #  <--- Correct the indentation here 
        
result=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for i in range (a):
    for j in range(b):
        result[i][j]=matrix1[i][j]+matrix2[i][j]
        
print("Result Matrix: ")
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        print(result[i][j], end=" ")
    print() #  <--- Correct the indentation here
```

**[Result]:**

> ```
> 1st Matrix: 
> 0 0 0 
> 4 4 4 
> 0 0 0 
> 2nd Matrtix: 
> 0 0 0 
> 4 4 4 
> 0 0 0 
> Result Matrix: 
> 0 0 0 
> 8 8 8 
> 0 0 0
> ```